# Unresolved reference: lparams for verticalLayout in Anko 0.10.6

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I've looked at [Anko 0.8 - unresolved lparams reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34351584/anko-0-8-unresolved-lparams-reference), but I'm not using lparams in the outermost layout like in that link.

I get 'unresolved reference: lparams' in the following code (and no import suggestions in Android Studio). Any ideas as to what I've missed and/or overlooked?

```
class LoginActivityUi: AnkoComponent<LoginActivity> {

    override fun createView(ui: AnkoContext<LoginActivity>): View = with(ui) {
        verticalLayout {
            backgroundColorResource = R.color.background_page

            textView{
                text = "ASDF"
            }.lparams{

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Here are my dependencies ($kotlin_version is 1.2.71, $anko_version is 0.10.6):

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'

implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"

// Appcompat-v7 (only Anko Commons)
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7-commons:$anko_version"

// Appcompat-v7 (Anko Layouts)
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:$anko_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-coroutines:$anko_version"

// Anko Layouts
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk15:$anko_version" // sdk15, sdk19, sdk21, sdk23 are also available
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7:$anko_version"

// Coroutine listeners for Anko Layouts
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-sdk15-coroutines:$anko_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-appcompat-v7-coroutines:$anko_version"

// CardView-v7
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-cardview-v7:$anko_version"

// Design
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design:$anko_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-design-coroutines:$anko_version"

// GridLayout-v7
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-gridlayout-v7:$anko_version"

// Percent
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-percent:$anko_version"

// RecyclerView-v7
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-recyclerview-v7:$anko_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-recyclerview-v7-coroutines:$anko_version"

// Support-v4 (only Anko Commons)
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-support-v4-commons:$anko_version"

// Support-v4 (Anko Layouts)
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-support-v4:$anko_version"

// ConstraintLayout
implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-constraint-layout:$anko_version"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so... As you can see in [this diff](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/commit/60761efa2274f26b000ae090eeb1c8bf23e5b0e1#diff-43f7c423ffa10f1892d08f5b16f22036), as of Anko 0.10.6 the `verticalLayout` methods have been modified to take initializer lambdas that are of type `LinearLayout.() -> Unit` instead of the previous `_LinearLayout.() -> Unit` types. The underscored `_LinearLayout` class is the one that defines the `lparams` methods that you're looking for, which is why it has gone missing due to this change.

There's already an open issue for this breaking change here: https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/issues/673

In the meantime, you can either stick with 0.10.5, or you can use `linearLayout` with an explicit orientation as a workaround:

```
linearLayout {
    orientation = LinearLayout.VERTICAL
    backgroundColorResource = R.color.background_page

    textView {
        text = "ASDF"
    }.lparams {

    }
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I've been wondering what the heck is up with this for so many hours. I was comparing and contrasting a different project where lparams worked fine (the outermost layout there wasn't a verticaLayout) and I was wondering why the heck that was.